CI/CD Flutter app for android using github action fails with the following error
This pipeline fails when build the flutter app using github action with the following error any idea?
For simplicity i added only the failar for one of my class in reallty it fails for all classes.
The builds and work perfectlly locally.
lib/routes/route.dart:2:8: Error: Error when reading 'lib/View/forgot_password_screen.dart': No such file or directory
import 'package:hogskoleprovet/View/forgot_password_screen.dart';

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  build:
    name: Build and Test
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    env:
      KEYSTORE_BASE64: ${{ secrets.KEYSTORE_BASE64 }}
      STORE_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.STORE_PASSWORD }}
      KEY_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.KEY_PASSWORD }}
      KEY_ALIAS: ${{ secrets.KEY_ALIAS }}

    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up JDK 11
        uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          distribution: 'zulu'
          java-version: '11'

      - name: Install Flutter
        uses: subosito/flutter-action@v2
        with:
          flutter-version: '3.22.1'  # Specify a fixed version

      - name: Clear Flutter Cache
        run: flutter clean
        working-directory: mobileapp

      - name: Cache Flutter Pub Dependencies
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        with:
          path: ~/.pub-cache
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-pub-cache-${{ hashFiles('hogskoleprovet_api/mobileapp/pubspec.yaml') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-pub-cache-

      - name: Flutter Pub Get
        run: flutter pub get
        working-directory: mobileapp

      - name: Run Unit Tests
        run: flutter test
        working-directory: mobileapp

      - name: Decode Keystore
        run: echo ${{ secrets.KEYSTORE_BASE64 }} | base64 --decode > mobileapp/android/app/upload-keystore.jks

      - name: Create key.properties
        run: |
          echo "storePassword=${{ secrets.STORE_PASSWORD }}" > mobileapp/android/key.properties
          echo "keyPassword=${{ secrets.KEY_PASSWORD }}" >> mobileapp/android/key.properties
          echo "keyAlias=${{ secrets.KEY_ALIAS }}" >> mobileapp/android/key.properties
          echo "storeFile=${{ github.workspace }}/mobileapp/android/app/upload-keystore.jks" >> mobileapp/android/key.properties

      - name: Build App Bundle
        run: flutter build appbundle --release
        working-directory: mobileapp

      - name: List Directory Structure After Build
        run: |
          echo "Listing directory structure after build:"
          ls -R mobileapp

      - name: Upload Build Artifacts
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: app-release
          path: mobileapp/build/app/outputs/bundle/release/app-release.aab


